# Communications between entities through service layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern

I have a project with Web layer in Asp.net MVC then Service layer for business logic and then Repository Layer for data access. I am using unity for dependency injection.

MVC -> Service -> Repository -> EF

I have Product service which is responsible for product related data operations and one is Order service which is responsible for Order saving, updating else. In some scenarios i want to access product data in Order service, for that i injected an instance of Product service into Order service instead of accessing Product repository directly into the Order service.

Here i want to know what would be the better approach or i should not access product data into order service? 
One drawback of injecting product instance is that whenever unity wants to create instance of Order service, it has to create an instance of Product service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing `Product` repository directly into `Order` service is the best approach to go.

Injecting more and more dependencies does not seems good alternative as you said in question. Though you are using DI framework, still there is a cost for it.

OTOH, Repository is lower layer for Service. One service should be definitely allowed to access any Repository. I do not see any technical or pattern related issue with this. In-fact, this resolves many issues.

Comment: Yes injecting service can also cause the cyclic reference. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you able to use Service locator pattern. In service locator you do not have to inject and service into another service.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/service-locator-pattern/

Answer (score 0):

In general in the MVC projects I've used, Services are usually composed of Repositories, but Services can also use other Services.  You just have to watch out for circular dependencies.  In some cases I've split a Service to avoid circular references usually because a Service grew too large or acquired more than a couple domain responsibilities.  So a ProductService might be split into ProductCalculatorService and ProductSearchService and only the latter is injected into the OrderService to avoid a circular dependency yet still maintain DRY code.